# Difference between x.controller and .controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I have a main app.js file which has the defined code as below:

```
var app = angular.module('Funapp', [
  'Funapp.controllers', 
  'Funapp.services', 
  ])
```

I'm wondering why for some of my js controller files, I can use app.controller while others I have to write angular.module(){} etc to use .controller instead? app.controller doesn't work for the second case.

For example. app.controller works for my posting controller.

```
'use strict';
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope, Post) { ...etc
```

But doesn't work in other js files like factory, so i have to type it as below

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Funapp.services', [])
.factory('Post', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {....etc
```

Doesn't work in the post view or dummy controller too, postview controller below

```
'use strict';
//angular.module('Funapp') --> Doesnt work currently, neither does Funapp.controller

app.controller('PostViewCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Post) { ...etc
```

Can someone enlighten me how to use app.controller and .controller, and if the latter, what should I consider typing in the angular.module("", [])?

I have read angular tutorials and do understand that angular.module("", []) defines the module while angular.module("") uses that defined module. However, been getting many errors that I'm unable to resolve the issues proper and understand how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on whether the main app definition file is already loaded and is in scope by the time you reach a view requiring `PostViewCtrl`. If it's already been loaded and is available to the DOM, it means you can use the `app.controller` syntax, obviously since you've already declared it and it's dependencies. If it's not available to the DOM, then you need to do what you're already doing, which is a pain and terrible from a best practices point of view. For example if you have a main page which has a script containing your app definition, the other views hosted within that shell page could have controllers declared by `app.controller`, but if you have say, server side views, and the main app definition script is not included in your master page (the ASP.NET concept) then you need to re-declare your app definition whenever you want to create a controller inside each of those server side views.

For example, say you have 2 pages, `Home` and `About`. Each have separate controller definitions in separate files:
`app.js` looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp", ['demoApp.services']);
var appServices = angular.module('demoApp.services', []);
```

That needs to be loaded upfront and needs to be around whenever you navigate to any other pages, since your other pages are part of the same app, and also need services define on that app.

`HomeCtrl.js`:

```
app.controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "Home!";
});
```

amd `AboutCtrl.js`:

```
app.controller("aboutCtrl", function ($scope,svc1) {
    $scope.msg = "About!";
    svc1.sayHi();
});
```

Now in `Home.html`:

```
<divng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
</div>
```

and `About.html`:

```
<script src="~/app/Svc1.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/AboutCtrl.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="aboutCtrl">{{msg}}</p>
```

And `Svc1.js` looks like this:

```
appServices.service("svc1", function () {
    return {
        sayHi: function () {
            alert("hi");
        }
    };
});
```

Long story short, the `app` and `appServices`variables, referencing your app modules, need to be in scope when you declare services or controllers on your app otherwise you have to redefine your app all the time.

Comment: In this case, if I wish to use app.factory for the second code, how do I change which files in order for that to be effective? Do I need to edit the main app.js definitions?

All my controllers are all in individually seperated js files.
<br></br>
The reason why I wish to change is my lack of understanding would probably lead me to potentially frustrating errors in my js files in future.

Comment: The same goes for services. The app that you create services for must also be loaded by the time you write: "app.service", the main thing is to have the module definition in place when you add services/controllers etc. to it. Load the `var appServices=angular.module('Funapp.services', [])` declaration on start up, and make sure it's available to all the pages that need it, now if you wish to create another service, given that the script containing the `appServices` varible is available, just do `appService.factory()`..

Answer (score 1):

You are on right track in namespacing your various objects, you need to define modules for each of your constructs.

Here's an example

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Funapp">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="PostsCtrl">

<div class="well">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

angular.module('Funapp.services', [])
    .service('PostService', [function () {
        return {
            doSomething: function() {
                    return "I posted something";
            }   
        }

    }]);

angular.module('Funapp.controllers', ['Funapp.services'])
    .controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', 'PostService', function ($scope, Post) {    
        $scope.message = Post.doSomething();
        console.log("I'm a Post Controller");
    }
    ]);

angular.module('Funapp', [
  'Funapp.controllers'
]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creating namespaces and modularizing an app is certainly good practice, but re-declaring the app every time because it's not available to the DOM is just code duplication and a maintenance nightmare IMO.

Comment: I'm not entire sure of your point @MohammadSepahvand, I will say that how you setup your code base really depends on the size of the app. We've broken up our fairly large app, at my work, in a functional setup and have many modules, instead of just one. And where you need shared things like services and filters, those get put into a common module. I do agree things can get out of hand if you are not careful and don't refactor when it looks like you'll have a maintenance nightmare. IMHO

Comment: I completely agree with what you said, but I'm just giving a heads up the OP not to put a patch on the problem but redefining the _same_ app everywhere.